# Customize “Add New Item” form in a Sharepoint 2013 List to pull parameters from the query string

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-designer, custom-form

I would like to customize the add new item form in a sharepoint list to pull a query string parameter and automatically set it as one of the lookup fields in the new item. I have found a perfect tutorial (http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/194253/How-to-Customize-the-New-Item-form-to-take-paramet) for how to do this in Sharepoint Designer 2010 in Sharepoint 2010 but design mode was removed Designer in 2013 so that tutorial is not of much use.

So basically what I'm asking is how do I do pull query string values in Sharepoint Designer 2013?

Answer (score 5):

In addition to customizing List Views & Forms via XSLT, with SharePoint 2013 was introduced a Client Side Rendering (CSR) technique. As an introductory please follow this article [Introduction to Client Side Rendering in SharePoint 2013](http://www.rbradbrook.co.uk/Blog/Post/10/Introduction-to-Client-Side-Rendering-in-SharePoint-2013).

Since CSR is the default rendering mode in SharePoint 2013, I would recommend this approach to customize a New Form page.

### Solution

Suppose a Tasks list that contains a `Task Category` lookup field.

Then the following rendering template could be used for setting `TaskCategory` lookup field value retrieved from a query string parameter named `cat`.

```
(function () {
    var ctx = {};
    ctx.Templates = {};
    ctx.Templates.Fields = {
        'TaskCategory': {
            'NewForm': renderTaskCategory
        }
    };
    SPClientTemplates.TemplateManager.RegisterTemplateOverrides(ctx);
})();


function renderTaskCategory(ctx) {
    var catId = GetUrlKeyValue('cat'); //extract cat parameter from a query string 
    ctx.CurrentFieldValue =  catId; //set lookup field value 
    return SPFieldLookup_Edit(ctx); //default template for rendering Lookup field control
}
```

Key points:

- Lookup field value is specified in the format: `LookupId`
- `GetUrlKeyValue` is a SharePoint specific function that serves for
  extracting parameter from a query string

### How to apply changes

In order to apply the changes we need to set the `JSLink` property of XLV web part:

- First of all, let's save this JS template and name it `Tasks.js`. Then upload the specified into SharePoint `Site Assets` library
- open New Form page in Edit mode and go to web part properties
- find under `Miscellaneous` group `JSLink` property and specify its value:
  `~sitecollection/SiteAssets/Task.js` as shown on figure below
  [image]

### Result

[image]

Comment: Vadim, how to create a  new custom form with hormal html controls, and other SP controls  for a  splist. is there any link, either from your blog or any other helpful step by step process. help is appreciated

Answer (score 2):

You can add content editor to page and refer a javascript file which will comtain code for reading the query string

To add content edit to to List//NewForm.aspx?toolpaneview=2 to edit the page and add webpart.