# How to handle this assignment

Tags: visual-studio

I have a blueprint that i am supposed to create on sharepoint.  I do not have much experience with sharepoint yet so i am not sure if i have decided on the right track.  I think not so maybe you guys can point me in the right direction.

I have a few lists i need to create, i have created the content types and the list definitions and instances.  No worries there, but here comes the 'difficult' part.

The create and edit form should have special button actions, and a different layout from the standard add/edit listitem sharepoint offers.  I have gone and hidden the lists on the menu and created visual web parts for them.  Displaying all list items and firing a popup to create a new one or to edit one.  This seemed like a good idea untill I noticed i had to send emails to users allowing them to directly open an item.  This is with my current code a problem.

How would you guys technically handle this assignment.  Can i actually alter the standard add/edit form and add button actions to it or am i on the right track using visual web parts?

If so where can i find good documentation about a better approach?

Answer (score 0):

Form modification should be used instead.

http://community.bamboosolutions.com/blogs/sharepoint-2013/archive/2012/09/20/how-to-create-custom-forms-using-sharepoint-designer-2013.aspx

[Customize “Add New Item” form in a Sharepoint 2013 List to pull parameters from the query string](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/111222/customize-add-new-item-form-in-a-sharepoint-2013-list-to-pull-parameters-from)

Or Infopath (old school)

http://chanakyajayabalan.wordpress.com/2013/06/20/individual-newedit-and-display-forms-for-sharepoint-using-infopath-forms/